# calling session object from jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have a asp.net button.  I add ajax.query call to a method on the code behind page. According to the 'rules' I have to declare this server side method as  'Public' and 'Static'. The issue with that is that I cannot invoke any asp.net controls or session objects within that method as the error 'an object reference is required~'.  I thought jquery was an alternative to the AJAX  ToolKit but where the ToolKit lets me invoke controls the jquery does not.  Is this correct or am I missing something here?

thanks

Comment: Why would you like to access the session from the client? Have you considered using cookies?

Comment: hi, thanks for replying.  It was more to do with accessing controls in my asp.net pages. i do not want use cookies as the User may not want them on...

Comment: you can access almost every control in your page via js, What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Hi, OK.  At the moment I have an asp.net button.  This calls a web service and I pass values I acquired from session objects and control values - like a selecteditem from a listbox. Then all these values are  passed to a socket connection which talks to a windows service which returns a sprite image then i play that sprite image using sprite.net framework.  I also populate a listbox with the value selected from a dropdown box. All using asp.net controls...

Comment: And you want to access the data in the asp.net controls from javascript?

Comment: well yes, from jquery. Reason being is that the AJAX toolkit from Microsoft seems not to work properly in some browser (like Chrome).  So i want this partial postback to work. Besides Jquery will look good on my CV :) (thanks all ur time btw)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37412/discussion-between-tomzan-and-andrew-simpson)